# blockstream API response

Tags: transactions, json-rpc, api, blockstream

How do I determine if the current transaction is an outgoing or an incoming transaction from looking at the following API response?

https://blockstream.info/api/address/1A6HUTtraLwTg48AwpQxPwLmTnDGSSJteG/txs

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If an address appears in the `vout` list, it is incoming for that address.

If the address is in the `vin` list, it is an outgoing transaction for that address.

Addresses may appear in both the `vin` and the `vout`.

Comment: If they appeared in both, is there a way for me to differentiate them?

Comment: If they appear in both, the address is both sending and receiving at least some of the coins in the entire transaction. The coins it is sending will be in the vin array, and the coins it is receiving will be in the vout.